# Sharing Date Value from one component to another component in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to share **date** between components in angular!

1. My components have no relation. So all methods of @Input and @Output will not work.
2. As stated my components are non-related so, you will say "try behaviourSubject" .... I have!
3. I am using devextreme angular forms.
4. I am using angular version 10.

Now the scene is
I have ANGULAR FORM in one component from where user selects the date.And when submits a service is called and data is shown in Grid.
I need to take that exact **date** selected by user in Form of 1st Component and place it inside the date selection field of 2nd Component.

Please Help Me!

Comment: Behaviour subjects are perfect for when components are not related, I don't see how it wouldn't solve your problem. Just make sure that one component is updating it , and other is subscribed to changes.

Comment: "_so, you will say "try behaviourSubject" .... I have!_" - where and how did you try it? The `BehaviorSubject` must be in a singleton service that could be accessed by both the components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Services and Subjects or Behavior Subjects for this purpose.

Follow the documentation link.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service

Answer (score 0):

When passing data between unrelated components, the `RxJS BehaviorSubject` seems very useful. So sharing date value from first component to second component is something like this which might help you:

**date.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DateService {

  private dateSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
  currentDate = this.dateSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeDate(date: any) {
    this.dateSource.next(date)
  }
}
```

**second.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DateService } from "../date.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  template: `
     {{date}}
   `,
   styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})

export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

  date: any;

  constructor(private dateService: DateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dateService.currentDate.subscribe(date=> this.date = date)
  }
}
```

**first.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DateService } from "../date.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  template: `
    {{date}}
    <button (click)="newDate()">New Date</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  date: any;

  constructor(private dateService: DateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  newDate() {
    this.dateService.changeDate(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

filter.comp.ts:`date: any;`

filter.comp.html:

```
 <input
                      
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Please Select the Date"
                      class="form-control"
                      [minDate]="minDate"
                      [maxDate]="maxDate"
                      #dp="bsDatepicker"
                      bsDatepicker [(ngModel)]="date"
                      [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true, dateInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }"
```

home.comp.ts:

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
this.FilterDate = this.scFilterComponent.date;
```

}